# What does <"> mean in an RFC? What about `#1`?

Tags: http, md5, rfc

In this RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#page-8 we have this:

> 3.2.1 The WWW-Authenticate Response Header
>
> If a server receives a request for an access-protected object, and
> an    acceptable Authorization header is not sent, the server responds
> with    a "401 Unauthorized" status code, and a WWW-Authenticate
> header as    per the framework defined above, which for the digest
> scheme is    utilized as follows:
>
> ```
>   challenge        =  "Digest" digest-challenge
>
>   digest-challenge  = 1#( realm | [ domain ] | nonce |
>                       [ opaque ] |[ stale ] | [ algorithm ] |
>                       [ qop-options ] | [auth-param] )
>
>
>   domain            = "domain" "=" <"> URI ( 1*SP URI ) <">
>   URI               = absoluteURI | abs_path
>   nonce             = "nonce" "=" nonce-value
>   nonce-value       = quoted-string
>   opaque            = "opaque" "=" quoted-string
>   stale             = "stale" "=" ( "true" | "false" )
>   algorithm         = "algorithm" "=" ( "MD5" | "MD5-sess" |
>                        token )
>   qop-options       = "qop" "=" <"> 1#qop-value <">
>   qop-value         = "auth" | "auth-int" | token
> ```
>
> The meanings of the values of the directives used above are as

In understand that `|` means concatenation, `[]` means that the thing can or can not appear. What does `1#` mean? What about `<">` and `1*SP`?
On the RFC begining there's no explanation for these.

Comment: The RFC (in [§1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617#section-1.1)) refers to another RFC (2616) for the augmented [Backus–Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). It is described in [RFC 2616 §2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-2.1).

Comment: ‘_In understand that `|` means concatenation_’ No, it means _either_.

Comment: What about `KD` in `      request-digest  = <"> < KD ( H(A1),     unq(nonce-value)
                                          ":" nc-value
                                          ":" unq(cnonce-value)
                                          ":" unq(qop-value)
                                          ":" H(A2)
                                  ) <">`?

Comment: on page 13. Couldn't find anything about `KD` on the RFC2616

Comment: "KD" is a function name described in the prose (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617#page-10). You really really should stop looking at historic specs. For the auth framework, see RFC 7235. For Basic and Digest, see RFC 7617 and RFC 7616.

Comment: @JulianReschke I'm looking at this because it's the spec for RTSP 1.0. Even though RTSP 2.0 exists, the majority of IP cameras today uses 1.0.

Comment: @Gatonito - the newer RFCs are just updated descriptions of the existing HTTP protocol. So they apply to RTSP 1.0 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are looking at outdated documents. For this piece, you should look at RFC 7235.
2. ABNF is defined in RFC 5234 (wtih extensions from RFC 7231). You should find those references based on the section "Syntax Notation" in RFC 7235.

(and, for FWIW, RFC 2617 points to the definitions as well, see Section 1.1).